# Ubuntu 14.04 (Gnome): Laptop Display Blank After Undocking

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, display, docking

I've been experiencing a really annoying issue with my recent Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 install. The OS is running on a Lenovo T440s.  At the office I have a dock that connects to two monitors, one is connected through VGA and one is connected through DVI.  So far, so good.

The problem starts when I put my laptop to sleep while it's docked and connected to these monitors.  When I wake the laptop (by opening the lid), say once I get home, the laptop appears to power on but the display is completely blank.  I cannot wake it by switching to the other tty sessions via <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>f1-6</kbd> or anything else.

I should add that this only seems to happen when transitioning to/from the docking station.  If while using the laptop as a laptop, I put it to sleep, I can wake it without problems so long as it's still in laptop mode (i.e. undocked).  If I use the laptop, put it to sleep, dock it, then press the power button, the monitors will be blank.  It's only after I open the lid that I get a display on both monitors and the laptop screen.

I know that this question gets asked a lot, I know because I've read just about every one of those posts and failed in applying their fixes to my setup.

I'm willing to set up some sort of xrandr script that runs in cron or gets triggered by some acpi state change.  I'm all ears!

Comment: I noticed something today.  If I have my laptop docked (connected to the monitors) and I sleep it, when I dock again and wake the laptop, it won't automatically display to the monitors.  I have to open the laptop lid, which causes the display to appear on the laptop and both monitors.  Once I close the laptop lid, the display stays on the monitors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1308674.
The bug seems to only be fixed in Kernel 3.14.